# All elements on the same line on mobile

Tags: html, css

so my problem is that I have a few elements under extra-search, but i can't seem to get them to be displayed on the same line when on mobile. My question is how can I make them resize when on mobile devices so that all the elements in the extra search are kept on the same line?

This is the website : http://www.onetechsearch.com/

```css
.width-container {
  max-width:1180px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
#topbar {
  background:#474747;
  padding:15px 0 0 0;
  min-height:70px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #000;
}

#picture-side {
  display: inline-block; 
  float:left;
  z-index: 8; 
  text-align:center;
}

#picture-side label {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#picture-side1 {
  display: inline-block; 
  float:left;
  z-index: 9; 
  text-align:center;
}
#picture-side1 label {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#picture-side2 {
  display: inline-block; 
  float:left;
  z-index: 10; 
}

#picture-side2 label {
  color: #ffffff;
}


#span.select2-selection__rendered {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}


input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ border-bottom: 5px solid lime; } 

.site-wrap {
  display: none;
}
#picture {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#picture2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#video {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#chkPassport {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#searchF label {
  height:40px; line-height:40px; text-align:center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}

#from-side {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #8a298a;
  background-color: #6b446b;
}

span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

#chkPassport label {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

#cat1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="width-container">
    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>

    <div id="search">
      <form action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/recipes" method="GET" id="searchF">
        <?php
$searched_term = get_query_var('recipe_search');
if (empty($searched_term)) {
$searched_term = isset($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : "";
}
?>
        <input id="sfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="keywords" <?php if (!empty($searched_term)) {echo 'value="'.$searched_term.'"';} ?>>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
        <label for="chkPassport">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkPassport" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" />
          Advanced Search
        </label>
        </div>  
    </div>  

    <div id="extra-search" div style="display:none;justify-content:center;align-items:center;margin: auto;width: 50%;" >
      <div id="picture-side">

        <input type="radio" name="images" value="1" id="picture" 
               <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='1'){ echo 'Checked';} ?>><label for="picture">With Pictures</label>
      </div>

      <div id="picture-side1">

        <input type="radio" name="images" value="0" id="picture2" 
               <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='0'){ echo 'checked';} ?>><label for="picture2">Without Pictures</label>
      </div>  

      <div id="picture-side2">

        <input type="radio" name="images" value="0" id="video" 
               <?php if(isset($_GET["video"]) && $_GET["video"]=='1'){ echo 'checked';} ?>><label for="video">With video</label> 
      </div>      


      <div id="time-side">
        <!--<small>Published time</small>-->
        <input type="text" id="from-side" name="from" placeholder="Start date"
               </div>


        <div id="cat1">
          <select id="cat" name="cat">
            <option value="all">All categories</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="C">Hawaji</option>
          </select> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please edit your question,which also not displayed desktop window too

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [@Media Query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to enable the application of specific css when the width of the browser page is a less / greater than a specific dimension.

For example, in your css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { 
    #extra-search { 
        display: inline-block; 
        width: 450px; 
        height: 100%; 
    }
}
```